# Is there an efficient way to verify the union of two RSA accumulators?

Tags: rsa, accumulators

More specifically, say we have one RSA accumulator $A_{S_1}$ accumulating set $S_1$ and another RSA accumulator $A_{S_2}$ accumulating set $S_2$. Does there exist a sublinear method to securely verify that another RSA accumulator $B$ accumulates the set $S_1 \cup S_2$, given only $A_{S_1}$ and $A_{S_2}$? All accumulators would be modulo the same $N$.

I suspect that billinear maps over composite groups may be enough, but I am not sure if building an RSA accumulator over one of these groups breaks its security.

For a definition of the RSA accumulator, refer to section 2.2 of this paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/625.pdf.

Comment: You might want to add the definition of the accumulator. They are not widely used, and I don't know if there is a standard construction.

Comment: Done! The RSA accumulator is fairly obscure, so hopefully the definition will help.

Comment: If $A_{S_1}$ and $A_{S_2}$ are disjoint and $B$ is given as a superset of either $A_{S_1}$ or $A_{S_2}$, then yes. Have a look at look at this [2018 paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1188.pdf) in section **Accumulator unions** on page 22